# Object variable not set issue while adding text in to a notes document field

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I did create a new form, where I have a table with 2 column's.

The last row of this table is the `status`.

I would like to do this: While my Notes Agent is running, it will go trough few action stepts. If one of the steps done, it should add the result of this action into a cell that I have definded.

Something like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| First action was done successfully.  |
| Second action was done successfully. |
| Third action was done successfully.  |
----------------------------------------
```

I tried the following code:

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim sess As NotesSession    
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument    
    Dim item As NotesItem

    Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase    
    Set doc = db.GetDocumentById("100B")

    'do some code stuff.....

    Set item = doc.AppendItemValue( "field_Status", "First action was done successfully." & Chr(13) )
    Call doc.Save( False, True )

    'do some code stuff.....

    Set item = doc.AppendItemValue( "field_Status", "Second action was done successfully." )
    Call doc.Save( False, True )
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I get always this message:

> Object variable not set

Im not sure what is missing and if this is actually the right way how to realize my idea in code. I hope you have an idea / hint for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: NEVER write even one line of code without error handler. 
That said: The easiest error handler would be

```
On Error Goto ErrorHandler

...your complete code goes here

EndOfRoutine:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  Messagebox Err & "," & Error & " in line " & Erl
  Resume EndOfRoutine
```

This would have given you this error line:

```
Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase
```

But wait: WHICH Object variable is not set?

Its "sess", as you only wrote:

```
Dim sess as NotesSession
```

Assigned, but not set... you need either:

```
Dim sess as New NotesSession
```

Or if you want to keep your line then just before the assignment of db:

```
Set sess = New NotesSession
```

Additional advice: finding a document via its NoteID is not a good Idea, and hardcoding it is even worse: the NoteId changes in different replicas. The same document will have a different NoteId in another replica of the database (e.g. A local replica or in a cluster). And if someone deletes that document and recreates it, then you need to update your code. Use a sorted view and GetDocumentByKey with a specific key you set in your document or a Profile document to store this information. Or at least use DocumentUniqueId, as this Is the same in every replica (though the recreation issue stays the same)

Comment: Torsten, thank you a million for your so easy and understandable answer. Also thank you for your advice, I will take care.

Comment: Torsten, short question, can I use the DocumentUniqueId in combination with the command `runOnServer(String noteID)` on javascript? I would be glad if you could check my question here, with more details: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517545/parameterdocid-gets-only-6-digit-of-my-documentuniqueid)