# ParameterDocID gets only 6 digit of my DocumentUniqueID

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Im calling from my Javascript application a specific IBM Notes agent. The call from Javascript to Notes agent happens with a parameter. This parameter is the Universal ID.

Unfortunately, my Agent gets only the 6 digit of my Universal ID (DocumentUniqueID). But I would like to have the full length of my UniversalID. What is missing, any idea?

**My Javascript:**

```
//more code before....

var UID = new String
UID$ = doc.getUniversalID()

// notes agent
var notesAgent = db.getAgent("NameOfMyNotesAgent");

// execute notes agent
var agentResult = notesAgent.runOnServer(UID$)
```

If I output my UID, its the full length of the Universal ID. This is no issue.

**My Notes Agent (NameOfMyNotesAgent):**

```
Dim agent As NotesAgent
Dim sess As New NotesSession    
Dim db As NotesDatabase

Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase   
Set agent = sess.CurrentAgent

Dim docUID As String    
docUID = agent.ParameterDocID

'Display Notes document UID
Print "******************************"
Print "Notes Document UID: " & docUID
Print "******************************"
' I only get the last 6 part of the DocumentUniqueID, not the full one. Why?
```

**Edit:**

I get the information from Knut Herrmann that this has to do with `runOnServer` which only accepts `noteID`.

Due to the NoteId changes in different replicas I would like to do this with `DocumentUniqueID`. Which way could I use for this, is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agent's `runOnServer(String noteID)` accepts only the noteId as parameter, not the UniversalId.

So, change your code to

```
var noteID = doc.getNoteID()
...
var agentResult = notesAgent.runOnServer(noteID)
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it. That's bad. I get the advice from Torsten Link in my previous question, not to use the noteID. Reason is, that this value can be change, if there is a replica of the db. Thats why I preferred the way over DocumentUniqueID. How could I realize that with the DocumentUniqueID - any possible solution?

Comment: Torsten's advice doesn't apply to this situation. You have a doc object already. Now you point to this document with the noteID and call runOnServer right away. This is safe.

Comment: Don't get me wrong:Right tool for the right question... You get your NoteID from the current document and runOnServer wants a NoteID... so nothing wrong with using a NoteID. Using noteid is only a bad idea when using it hardcoded or using it over multiple servers... for this example it is perfect

Comment: Ohhh.. Now I get it. Thanks a lot to both of you and sorry for the circumstances.

Comment: Also, never store a NoteID to use it on a later date. By the time you use it, it might have changed.